# GoogleChromeFrame won't load if launched from mail

Tags: internet-explorer, outlook, google-chrome-frame

I have installed GCF on my machine.
I configured a test website with `X-UA-Compatible` so GCF will be used. 
It works if I type the url, click it from history or favorites.

But if I click the url from a mail in an Outlook 2007 client, it doesn't. 
Plain IE is used. GCF is not loaded.

If clicked from Webmail, it works

How can I make it work even from Outlook ?